# nth derivative hypergeometric funcion

Tags: derivatives, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I have a very complicated function

$f(x,y)= \Gamma{(a+ \sqrt{a-x^2})} \Gamma{(a- \sqrt{a-x^2})} \ _2F_1(b+\sqrt{a-x^2},b-\sqrt{a-x^2},2,1+y/4)$

$a>0$

I would like to know the expresion of the nth $x$ derivative of $f$ but as that is too complicated,
is there any way to at least have an aproximate form or bounds of the nth derivatives?

Comment: Where did you find this monster ?

Comment: Quantum fields in Ads space time. Yeah, I hate the universe.